# Breaking change in C++11 with make_pair(_Ty1&& _Val1, const _Ty2& _Val2)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++11, g++

Consider the following C++ Program

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 5, b = 7;
    auto pair = std::make_pair<int, int>(a,b);
    return 0;
    }
```

Using VC11 and also in [gcc-4.7.2 fails](http://ideone.com/g3Wcne) with different errors, though it seems to be related and VC11 error message is more meaningful

```
You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue
```

What I understand from this failure is

1. VC11 and I suppose gcc-4.7.2 have only one implementation of std::make_pair `make_pair(_Ty1&& _Val1, const _Ty2& _Val2)` which can accept only an rvalue reference. Prior VC++ version example VC10 had two versions, one to accept an lvalue and another an rvalue reference
2. Rvalue reference cannot be used to initialize a non const reference i.e. `int & a = b * 5` is invalid.
3. I could have used `std::move` to convert the `lvalue` to `rvalue` reference and the call would be successful.
4. As `std::make_pair` accepts two different types for each of the parameters, Template Argument Resolution in all possible cases can resolve the type of the parameter and an explicitly specifying the type is not required.

This scenario seems trivial and the incompatibility can easily be resolved by removing the explicit type specification and making the definition as

```
auto pair = std::make_pair(a,b);
```

- Now, my question is, what is the driving factor to remove the lvalue implementation from the library?
- Is it possible to know any other library functions which has been changed in similar ways?
- How to handle these situations when I need to target multiple compilers like g++, CC, aCC, XL C++ where either the compilers have not been upgraded or the compiler isn't supporting the rvalue reference and or move semantics.

Comment: Well, it sin't a breaking change, because who on earth uses `std::make_pair` with explicit template instantiation? It's *explicitly designed* to profit from automatic type deduction. So since rarely anybody would write `std::make_pair<int,int>` in favour of `std::make_pair`, there isn't much code to be broken. Well, nice find, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have encountered code where explicit type was  specified.

Comment: I believe this is the same issue that is discussed at [http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43785](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43785)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::make_pair`  exists for the sole purpose of exploiting type deduction to avoid typing the names of the types. That's why there is only one overload (and it should take two [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), not one universal reference and an lvalue reference to const as VC seems to think).

```
template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
```

If you want to type the types explicitly, you can just use the pair constructor. It is even shorter...

```
auto pair = std::pair<int, int>(a,b);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood the above fact though the hard way. Btw, Can you please explain what `universal reference` means? This term is new to me. Also are you ware of any other library functions which was changed similarly?

Comment: @Abhijit I added a link to Scott Meyer's explanation (he came up with the term). Any other library function that serves the same purpose (exploiting type deduction) is likely to not work if you don't use type deduction. They are often of the form `make_something`, like `make_tuple`. The point is that they don't work with explicit types because they are not useful with explicit types.

Comment: @Abhijit To be clear, "universal reference" is just a colloquial term. They really are just rvalue references, but because of the template type deduction and reference collapsing rules, they have an interesting property - they sometimes behave like lvalue references and other times like rvalue references. Come to think of it, we should call this *lvalue-rvalue duality*.

Comment: Thank you and @sftrabbit for taking time in answering my doubt.

Answer (score 21):

When you do `std::make_pair<int, int>`, you are forcing the template arguments `T1` and `T2` to both be deduced as `int`. This gives you the function as `std::pair<int,int> make_pair(int&&, int&&)`. Now these arguments can only take rvalues because they are rvalue references.

However, when the types of `T1` and `T2` are being deduced by template type deduction, they act as "universal references". That is, if they receive an lvalue argument they will be lvalue references and if they receive an rvalue argument they will be rvalue references. This gives `make_pair` the ability to do perfect forwarding.

So the point is, don't explicitly give the template type arguments. The whole point of `make_pair` is that it deduces the types itself. If you name the types, it can't do perfect forwarding any more and will fail for lvalue arguments.